# Numpy add one array to another one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Let

```
A = np.array([])

B = np.array([1,2])
C = np.array(["hey"])
D = np.array([])
```

I'm looking for a function which can append the arrays B,C,D to A. But not the values, the whole array:

So A should look like this:

```
A = np.array([[1,2],["hey"],[])
```

Append doesn't work, and concatenate as well as stack etc. don't work either because the arrays don't necessarily have the same shape. Is there someway to, for example, specify the type when appending?

Comment: You may consider using a list here.

Comment: You're missing a bracket in the last snippet

Comment: As pointed by @MadPhysicist, 'num' in numpy stands for 'numerical'. It's designed and optimised for numerical computations. While you can still hack around to use it with generic `dtype=object` it typically makes no sense since you then can't leverage the optimizations otherwise available, and you are usually better off using native python lists. What are you trying to achieve in the end? If you are doing large data manipulation, you can also consider pandas instead of numpy...

Comment: I don't like to see "doesn't work" in SO questions.  Show the actual code and error.  `np.append(np.append(np.append(A,B),C),D)` does run.  So does `np.concatenate([A,B,C,D])`.  Explain what's wrong with those, and what did you learn from that.

Comment: That last expression `np.array([[1,2],["hey"],[])` does run - but with a prominent **warning**.  Doesn't that tell you anything significant?

Answer (score 1):

Appends are not done in-place in numpy, since it operates on fixed buffers. Since your lists are ragged and inhomogenous, you can do:

```
A = np.array([B, C, D])
```

The dtype will automatically be `object` in this particular case, and the result will be an array of arrays.

This essentially defeats the purpose of using numpy: arrays are slower than lists when it comes to append and delete operations. Instead, it may be better to use a list:

```
A.extend([B, C, D])
```

Alternatively, if you are trying to describe a structured datatype, you can do that effectively with numpy:

```
dt = np.dtype([('b', float, 2), ('c', 'U3'), ('d', float, 0)])
A = np.array([(B, C.item(), D)], dtype=dt)
```